# Multiple regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

```
time = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' , f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print time.group()
```

and

```
number = re.search(r'[TEL:+]\d+\n', f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print number.group()
```

both code works fine individually , but when I try to run in single script like this :

```
number = re.search(r'[TEL:+]\d+\n', f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print number.group()

time = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' , f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print time.group()
```

second pattern didn't worked .

```
print time.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the first `read()` consumes the whole file.

You should reset the pointer after the first `read()` as follows:

```
number = re.search(r'[TEL:+]\d+\n', f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print number.group()

f.seek(0,0)

time = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' , f.read().decode('utf-16'))
print time.group()
```